# THREE.JS's Loading Manager Not a function?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create a loading manager in my application using THREE.JS. However, when I code and declare a new THREE.LoadingManager, I received an error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" . May I know if the newer version of THREE.JS has another function that replaces the loading manager. If so, what is it?

```
//some code here

window.onload = function(){
    //some more code here

    //loading manager
   var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
            manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {

                console.log( item, loaded, total );

            };

    var texture = new THREE.Texture();
    var onProgress = function (xhr){
        if(xhr.lengthComputable){
            var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
            console.log(Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded');
        }
    };

    var onError = function(xhr){

    };
//The rest of the code
}
```

follow-up: I have open up three.min.js and specifically searched for LoadingManager and did not find such function... I tried to look into the example in http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_obj . In their version of THREE.JS, there is such thing as LoadingManager. However, in the new one, there is no such function. I would like to know what is the new function that they use... Thanks!

Comment: what version of three.js are you using? you probably need to update to the latest one; r71.

Comment: Does the new three js has that function? I downloaded it right off the webste

Comment: yeap; at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/loaders/LoadingManager.js and https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/build/three.js

Comment: CDN version has this function - http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r73/three.js